# Change db table name in EF4 (entity framework 4)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Does anyone know how to change the mapped db table for an entity in EF4 (entity framework 4)?

Later edit: I think i've found the place where the table names are defined, in the model browser. But their names are readonly, so it's not possible to edit them using the designer. Also, there's no reference (from what i've searched) to the table name in the xml schema.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you just need to change the name of the table you can:

1. Open EDMX file with XML Editor.
2. Locate SSDL section in it.
3. Locate entity set element for example `<EntitySet Name="Customers" EntityType="ExampleModel.Store.Customers" Schema="dbo" />`.
4. Add `Table="MyTableName"` attribute. `<EntitySet Name="Customers" EntityType="ExampleModel.Store.Customers" Schema="dbo" Table="MyTableName" />`

Here is a complete [CSDL, SSDL, MSL specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399604.aspx).

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you will have to change this every time you re-gen your db mappings.

Comment: This is not a practical approach as Zacho mentioned.

Answer (score 12):

An alternative solution would be to override a method in your `DbContext` class.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("DB_PRODUCTS_TBL");
        // otherwise EF assumes the table is called "Products"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe what you are asking is reconfigure the mapping of an entity to a table. You can right click an entity and select table mapping. This would show you the entity the table is mapped. You can change the table in there. However when you open the dropdown, you will only see the table that you have imported using the Update Model wizard. If the table is not imported, it will not be listed. You can then map the properties appropriately to the column names of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a stored proc that changes the table name, passing the tablename as a variable. Then import the stored proc into EF4.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ChangeTableName
    @TableName varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC sp_rename "User", @TableName
END
GO
```

Comment: But i can't see how importing the stored procedure will update the schema. 
I think i didn't make clear what i'm trying to achieve, i'm trying to change the table to which an ef schema is mapped to, for example now it's retrieving data from table x in the database, i want it to retrieve data from table y now, both tables exist in the database, both have the exact same structure. The reason why i can't simply import data from one table to the other is because one table is used by some applications that can't be modified, and all applications need to access the same data. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I see the problem. Need to dynamically update the EF Schema, after renaming the table.

Comment: This may work in a small local project, but in an enterprise environment this would be totally unacceptable.  Who knows what is touching those table names.

Answer (score 0):

In the Model Browser or design surface right-click the entity and select properties. In the properties window edit the field "Entity Set Name".

This worked for me, however I was designing the schema first and then generating the database.

Answer (score 0):

Because I created my database first, I did the following:

1. Backed up the *.edmx file.
2. Changed my database table name.
3. Did as you suggested by renaming the Entity Set Name in the properties.
4. I then Updated the model based on my database by right-clicking the entity.
5. I noticed that the *.edmx file was missing half the lines, so I overlayed the *.edmx file with my backup, opened it in notepad, and did a replace all of my old table name with my new table name.
6. Rebuilt the MVC Application, tested, and it worked.

> **Note**: Whether all these steps above are needed I don't know, it's just
>   what I tried and it worked for me.