# Entity Framework 4 table name prefix

Tags: database, entity-framework-4, prefix

I would like to know, in a database first approach, if it is possible to automatically strip prefixes from table names.

For example table name is:

```
Core_Customers
```

I would like that to be just `Customers`.

Or is this only possible by editing all the class names in the edmx model?

Answer (score 0):

I think the designer is generated every time you generate your model so even if you change it in it might not be permanent.It's probably only possible by editing all the class names in the edmx model. Here is  [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276955/change-db-table-name-in-ef4-entity-framework-4) post though!