# EF - Import a new table from DB and have it replace an existing one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model, edmx

So I need to update the model from the db. The issue is that I want the new table to replace an existing one.

This is the format of my existing table.

[image: Original Table]

Here is the new table after import it from the DB.

[image: New Table]

I delete the original table and rename the fields to match, build and get errors.
I am getting errors because it can't find UserProfileTenant. When I use intellisense I see that it has USR_PROFILE_TENANT2 instead of UserProfileTenant.

I'm not sure where I need to update to have names properly updated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through some questions I found [Change DB in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3276955/7617). But the accepted answer isn't the one I used.  Its this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276955/change-db-table-name-in-ef4-entity-framework-4/3286436#3286436) by [zeeshanhirani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384610/zeeshanhirani).

Besure to also update the column mappings after the new table is selected.