# How to specify different table names than entities in EF4?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a number of entities in my EF4-Model like `Contacts`, `Calls`, `ContactTypes` etc.
When I generate the DB of the model, I get table names with the same naming.

How would I set the table names with a prefix `ab_Contacts`, `ab_Calls` etc but yet leave the entities as `Contacts` and `Calls` in the generated code?

I wasn't able to find a way to specify this in the .edmx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use model first you should not need this. Model first is for scenarios where you have no requirements on your database.

Changing this behavior requires change to generation process of SSDL part of your EDMX (which is created once you ask designer to generate SQL for you). By default this process is handled by workflow (`%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\TablePerTypeStrategy.xaml`) or it can be handled by T4 templates if you install [Database Generation Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87). You will have to modify either workflow (implement some custom generation component) or T4 template to use your custom naming convention.

**Edit:**

OK. I decided to try it myself to make the answer complete even I believe that pointing to the correct way should be enough.

When you install the Database Generation Power Pack you get a new set of templates and workflows installed on the above mentioned path. One of the workflows is called `Generate T-SQL Via T4 (TPT).xaml`. The difference between this workflow and original `TablePerTypeStrategy.xaml` is that this one is using external T4 templates to generate SSDL and MSL. What you need to do is create copy of this workflow and place it to the same directory (you must get it a different name). You must also create a copy of refereced T4 template for SSDL creation called `CSDLToSSDL_TPT.tt` and also place it to the same directory (with different name). Once you have copy of .tt file open the new .xaml file and change path to the SSDL template to the new one (either in designer in VS or in any text editor). As last step you must open your copy of .tt file and update `EntitySet` element creation:

```
foreach (EntityType entityType in edm.GetAllEntityTypes()) { #>
    <EntitySet Name="<#=WriteEntityTypeName(entityType, edm)#>" EntityType="<#=ssdlModelNamespace#>.<#=WriteEntityTypeName(entityType, edm)#>" Table="prefix_<#=WriteEntityTypeName(entityType, edm)#>" store:Type="Tables" Schema="<#=databaseSchemaName#>" />
<#  }
```

I have added `Table` attribute with name specifying `prefix_` (you can replace it with your own). Now you must select your new workflow in *Generate database from model* wizard and create a new SQL script.

Comment: Hi, I have done exactly as you suggested. But when editing the T-SQL VIA T4 (TPT).xaml file what do I have to change to get an "ab_" prefix in front of all generated tables? I am using the extension you recommended. many thanks

Comment: I believe it should take the name from SSDL if it doesn't you can still update template from SQL creation but make sure that correct table name is used in SSDL otherwise it will not work.

Comment: So are you saying I have to open the EDMX file with an XML editor and modify the SSDL section myself?  But then I had to do this everytime I want to the remapping as it will be overwritten. Is there a beter way or tutorial for this? Many Thanks

Comment: No that section should be correctly generated by already modified workflow or template and then it will be used for SQL generation.

Comment: sorry I am not sure how this is done. how do i modify the template to achieve this?

Comment: I just pointed you to the direction where it can be done. I don't know the exact place. I would have to install the extension myself and explore it for you ... As I mentioned you are doing it the hard way because model first is not supposed for this.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much. It wasn't really straight forward. It works but there is a little caveat.  I have clicked on "Create a Clone on Current Project". It made a file in my project with the suffix Clone. But this line within there gets reset every time I do an DB update from model: <dbtk:CsdlToSsdlTemplateActivity SsdlOutput="[Ssdl]" TemplatePath="CSDLToSSDL_TPTClone.tt" /> to <dbtk:CsdlToSsdlTemplateActivity SsdlOutput="[Ssdl]" TemplatePath="$(VSEFTools)\DBGen\CSDLToSSDL_TPT.tt" /> Not sure why it keeps overwriting it...

Comment: I ave found out why. The Workflow Clone is added to the project and the changes from the editor behind get ignored. Its kind of odd that you have to include these files to the project to run the extension. The drawback is that my project won't build as long as these files are included.

Comment: Don't add those files to the project. They are not part of the project but part of development environement.

Answer (score 0):

In your Context you can override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) and do something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().ToTable("ab_Contact");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this ..

If you just need to change the name of the table you can:

1. Open EDMX file with XML Editor.
2. Locate SSDL section in it.
3. Locate entity set element for example `<EntitySet Name="Customers" EntityType="ExampleModel.Store.Customers" Schema="dbo" />`.
4. Add `Table="MyTableName"` attribute. `<EntitySet Name="Customers" EntityType="ExampleModel.Store.Customers" Schema="dbo" Table="MyTableName" />`

Here is a complete [CSDL, SSDL, MSL specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276955/change-db-table-name-in-ef4-entity-framework-4).

Hope that helps.

taken from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276955/change-db-table-name-in-ef4-entity-framework-4)

Answer (score 0):

In EF6 simply change the entityset name property in the entity property

HTH
Lorenzo