# How can I bind my MVC Model to a different table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This seems like an easy question but I can't seem to find the answer.

I have a Model that looks like this ...

```
public class Application
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string LeadProgrammer { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionStringCode { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

My actual table name is DBA_APPLICATIONS ... the model is, of course, just looking for dbo.Applications.  How can I change this routing to the actual table?

Comment: Have you looked into the mappings? Your class name can be mapped to different table name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276955/change-db-table-name-in-ef4-entity-framework-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in your `ApplcationDBContext` class.

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Application>().ToTable("DBA_APPLICATIONS");
        // otherwise EF assumes the table is called "Applications"
    }
}
```