# Entity Framework: Reflecting table rename action

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, edmx, table-rename

Is it possible to reflect a database table name change in an .edmx file by simply using the XML Editor? I was hoping that making this change in the EntitySet node would be sufficient, but it seems not.

Receive a "error 0040: <> type is not defined in namespace <>" message.

This is purely a database table name change with no structural changes to the table and we are using POCO objects with EF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we can do this through the XML Editor; given that we are just doing a table rename and not changing the structure of the table in itself.

In our case it makes sense as the original database was not pluralizing the table so we just had to add a 's' or an 'es' in most cases; so we did not have to make any changes to the conceptual model.

Under the  -->  change the Table attribute to your new table name.

Ref: [Change db table name in EF4 (entity framework 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276955/change-db-table-name-in-ef4-entity-framework-4)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible but very very messy.

You need to change the [SSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399559%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as well as the [CSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399292%28v=vs.100%29).

Comment: What would you recommend in that case? Dropping the entity and recreating it again along with all the associations? I was hoping to be able to accomplish this instead with some judicious use of find and replace.

Comment: Can't you just do an update model from database? (Seems like there was an option for that).

Comment: Yes this is possible, however it creates a whole new set of entities and associations; which then results in the new set getting a suffix of 1. Just a bit too messy for me, so made the change in the SSDL using the Table attribute. Its just a single change and seems to work well thus far. Will keep the forum posted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nishan Might want to check this out: http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-model-comparer-for-entity.html