# Is MVC smoking under the hood? Mysterious entity rename

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

In my model:

```
public class ContractCategory
    {
        public int ContractCategoryID { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Charge> Charges { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ContractParentItem> ContractParentItems { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ContractChildItem> ContractChildItems { get; set; }
    }
```

and in my context:

```
public DbSet<ContractCategory> ContractCategorys { get; set; }
```

upon my `update-database -verbose` i get:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContractCategories] (
    [ContractCategoryID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ContractCategories] PRIMARY KEY ([ContractCategoryID])
)
```

ContractCategor **ies**?!?

**ies?**

Yes ContractCategorys mispelling was intentional, i wanted to conform with the appendage "s"

Why did MVC change it?

**UPDATE**
I guess it's smarter than I had thought!  I thought pluralization only happens with an appendage of an "s".

Comment: Not sure if joking or not, but that is the correct plural of category.  More than one category is categories.  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/category (see item #4)

Comment: not a joke, i wrote ContractCategorys intentionally just wanted to append an s

Comment: That looks like the correct pluralization of `ContractCategory` - do you not want the plural form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change db table name in EF4 (entity framework 4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276955/change-db-table-name-in-ef4-entity-framework-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will automatically pluralize the entity name for the table name.

If you don't wish this behaviour, you can turn it off in your `DbContext` subclass:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Or explicitly map it to a table. Either use annotations or fluent API (`.ToTable("Categorys")`).

Answer (score 0):

Not being smarmy here, but the correct pluralizing of ContractCategory would be ContractCategories, so that's why you get that.

If you really want it spelled that way, EF lets you change the name of the table you're saving to.

See this answer here: [Change db table name in EF4 (entity framework 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276955/change-db-table-name-in-ef4-entity-framework-4)

Comment: This answer didn't deserve a down vote.  It is correct information, based on the original question, it was not clear if the OP understood the correct pluralization or if the 's' was intentional.

Comment: I humbly disagree as my note preceeded the answer submission.  Either way, the answer should of been removed upon my clarification. @Tommy

Comment: I put the answer in before I saw your clarification. Remember, StackOverflow doesn't update the question in real time as I'm researching the answer for you. And note, I was trying to be as polite as I could be, hence the "Not being smarmy here" beginning.

Comment: @CubanX Point 1 OK..(I'm sorry), Point 2 Invalid

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if possible, you can use an underscore. From experience entities with underscores do not get renamed so Contract_Category would become Contract_Categorys.