# Making Entity Framework Aware of Tables/Column Renames

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, edmx

While Renaming Tables or Columns, how to ensure the edmx's "Update Model from Database" recognizes the new Table Structure?

**MyTable** has only 2 columns.

```
ID
name
```

Refactor --> Rename (Ctrl R + R)

```
myTableID
fullName
```

Which of the following would be the "right" corresponding edmx changes, so the application works without runtime/Compile errors

1. Refactor --> Rename on the Edmx File or
2. Right Click --> Update Model From Database, delete old item or
3. Manually create, Delete and Validate the edmx

As you can see, its a very simple rename.

Compile Error

Run-Time Error : 
        EFControl _current  error CS0103: The name '_current' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Nope. I've failed atleast 7 times. Just don't know what the catch is yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: RENAMING COLUMNS**
I see your question has changed, since you are asking about renaming columns, so I'm updating my answer.
Let's follow your new example and create your table via T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].MyTable
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [name] NCHAR(10) NULL
)
```

Entity Framework (EF) will create the MyTable.cs file for you:

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the main section of your EDMX:

```
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="database1Model" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
    <EntityContainer Name="database1Entities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true" >
      <EntitySet Name="MyTables" EntityType="database1Model.MyTable" />
    </EntityContainer>
    <EntityType Name="MyTable">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="Id" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="name" Type="String" MaxLength="10" FixedLength="true" Unicode="true" />
    </EntityType>
  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
```

Then you rename your columns, using e.g. Visual Studio Server Explorer, which will generate this T-SQL (I didn't insert any data in MyTable):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [myTableID]   INT        NOT NULL,
    [fullName] NCHAR (10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([myTableID] ASC)
);
```

At this point, if you update your EDMX from database, you'll get this:

[image]

So, if you open your EDMX file and remove the three elements followed by `<!-- REMOVE --->`, as shown below:

```
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="database1Model" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
    <EntityContainer Name="database1Entities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true" >
      <EntitySet Name="MyTables" EntityType="database1Model.MyTable" />
    </EntityContainer>
    <EntityType Name="MyTable">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" /><!-- REMOVE -->
        <PropertyRef Name="myTableID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="Id" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" /><!-- REMOVE -->
      <Property Name="name" Type="String" MaxLength="10" FixedLength="true" Unicode="true" /><!-- REMOVE -->
      <Property Name="myTableID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="fullName" Type="String" MaxLength="10" FixedLength="true" Unicode="true" />
    </EntityType>
  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
```

and update from your model, you're good to go. Even your auto-generated file MyTable.cs will be updated with the new names:

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    public int myTableID { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
}
```

---

**ANSWER TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION: RENAMING A TABLE**
One way to do it is editing your .EDMX file, which Entity Framework created for you and where it stores all information regarding mapping the database to your objects.
This file can be found in the root folder of your project, i.e. where the .csproj file resides, and is just an XML that you can open with a text editor

1. Outside VisualStudio, e.g. PsPad, NotePad++ etc.
2. Or right-clicking it inside Visual Studio, choosing "Open with..." and picking "XML (Text) Editor".

I guess your `Foo` class corresponded to the `Foo` table; the latter now will probably be `FooNew` or something similar.

To rename the table but keep the `Foo` class, just look for this part of your EDMX file:

```
<!-- SSDL content -->
<edmx:StorageModels>
...
    <EntitySet Name="Foo" ... Schema="dbo" ... />
...
</edmx:StorageModels>
```

Inside the `EntitySet` add `Table="FooNew"` as attribute, as advised by the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276955/change-db-table-name-in-ef4-entity-framework-4):

```
<EntitySet Name="Foo" ... Schema="dbo" ... Table="FooNew" />
```

At this point, close and save; reopen the edmx double-clicking it and then  "Update Model From Database" like you did before.

Comment: Hey Francesco, This still gives me an error on the Entity framework mappings.

Comment: What happens? Can you provide some more details?

Comment: A Run-Time Error for the Root Entity Framework mapping : EFControl _current error CS0103: The name '_current' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @DLNarasimhan I updated my answer (and tested it, as you can see).